# Column in pandas dataframe in the form D/M/YY to two datetime variables

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I currently have a df in pandas called `astrology` that contains two columns, one column called birthdate has dates that I would like to create two new DateTime variables from )one variable to record the month and day and another variable to record the year).

My current df looks like this:

```
    birthdate   howMuch
       1/1/95   8
      3/15/80   7
      5/28/86   1
     11/16/61   5
     12/15/88   2
```

Desired df:

```
    month-day   year   howMuch
       1-1      1995    8
       3-15     1980    7
       5-28     1986    1
       11-16    1961    5
       12-15    1988    2
```

The current code I tried is:

```
astrology['year'] =  pd.to_datetime(astrology['.birthdate'])
```

And I get the error:

```
OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 7545-07-14 00:00:00
```

Comment: From the error, it seems that your data is not clean. It contains a birthdate `7545-07-14`.

Comment: It's working fine in `pandas 1.0.3`. Try updating your pandas version. If this didn't work then the problem is with that particular value.

Comment: @SandeepKadapa I'm working in python 3...

Comment: @QuangHoang I will clean it more and try again.

Comment: @QuangHoang cleaning worked...if you want to type that up as an answer with the code to create the month-day and year variables themselves, I can accept the answer! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First is possible test if cleaning is correct, check if some datetimes which cannot be parsed with [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and parameter `errors='coerce'` so not parsed datetimes are `NaT`, filtered are by [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (astrology[pd.to_datetime(astrology['birthdate'], errors='coerce').isna()])
```

Then converting to datetimes, for format of month and days is used [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) and for years [`Series.dt.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.year.html), but is necessary subtract `100` for avoid parsing years above today year:

```
dates =  pd.to_datetime(astrology['birthdate'])
y = dates.dt.year
now = pd.to_datetime('now').year
astrology = astrology.assign(monthday = dates.dt.strftime('%m/%d'),
                             year = y.mask(y > now, y - 100))
print (astrology)
  birthdate  howMuch monthday  year
0    1/1/95        8    01/01  1995
1   3/15/80        7    03/15  1980
2   5/28/86        1    05/28  1986
3  11/16/61        5    11/16  1961
4  12/15/88        2    12/15  1988
```

If want month day column without padding zeros is used here [`Series.str.rsplit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html) with selecting first lists by indexing `str[0]`:

```
md = astrology['birthdate'].str.rsplit('/', n=1).str[0]
dates =  pd.to_datetime(astrology['birthdate'])
y = dates.dt.year
now = pd.to_datetime('now').year
astrology = astrology.assign(monthday = md,
                             year = y.mask(y > now, y - 100))
print (astrology)
  birthdate  howMuch monthday  year
0    1/1/95        8      1/1  1995
1   3/15/80        7     3/15  1980
2   5/28/86        1     5/28  1986
3  11/16/61        5    11/16  1961
4  12/15/88        2    12/15  1988
```